# Code works well while running from Visual studio but .Exe hangs for the same

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, exe

I have a c# winform application, when I run it from Code, from Visula studio, It works well. But when I built exe for the same and running the same Hangs after working well for some time even it shows 0% CPU utilization in Hang state.

Hoping for a little help for solving the same problem would be very much useful from PRO people here.

Answer (score 9):

Even a pro would have a pretty hard time diagnosing the problem without even a single line of code posted.

But that's okay: we can help you help yourself. :)

Run the program without Visual Studio, wait for it to hang. Then start up Visual Studio and use the "Debug/Attach to process..." command to attach the debugger to the hung process, pause execution, and take a look at what it's doing (or not doing).

Comment: I was not aware of this functionality. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir Peter, as I did not know that in 2 forms and about 1K LOC, which part of code is creating issue, so could not post the code here. But I will use your solution for sure, once again thanks for that.